# Is Pandas included in EPD Free

Tags: enthought

The enthought site says pandas is included but I've installed on both windows and Linux and doing a 'import pandas' gives a "ImportError: No module named pandas found". Is pandas included with EPD Free 7.3?

Update :

Ok think I was slightly misled by the EPD Free download page which says that EPD includes pandas but if you go to the detailed list of libraries pandas is not included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EPD Free 7.3 installer did not ship with Pandas, and hence the import error.  But, if you have a registered EPD Free account, you can use `enpkg` to install `pandas`.  Look at this [support page](https://support.enthought.com/entries/22415022-Using-enpkg-to-update-EPD-packages) for more info.

Comment: @user2194615 please mark this as the answer (click on the check mark) rather than commenting to that effect; otherwise the question will keep showing as unanswered. More info at http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask . Thanks!